# What does 'cvs history -w' do?

Tags: cvs

I'm trying to determine the time of the last `cvs update` operation performed in a given working copy, and it's proving difficult. `cvs history -w` is documented as 'Show only the records for modifications done from the same working directory where history is executing' - but they must mean something else, because it doesn't do that at all (as far as I can see).

I would expect that if I check out a project from a repository for the first time, then make a couple small changes, `cvs history -e -w` would report only those modifications - but it still reports every change made in the repository, including changes made in different projects.

For example, take the following situation:

- $CVSROOT contains two projects - project-one and project-two
- `cvs history` returns several lines of output from modifications to project-one

If I run the following:

```
mkdir /home/lmitchell/cvs-repo
cd /home/lmitchell/cvs-repo
cvs checkout project-two
echo "//comment" >> bar.cpp
cvs commit bar.cpp
```

I would then expect `cvs history -w` to return me only a single line of output - the checkout operation - and I would expect `cvs history -e -w` to return me two lines - the checkout operation and the commit operation. However, it still returns history from everywhere in the repository, exactly as shown above. As a matter of fact, I haven't seen a change in output yet (over the last several hours of trying) from adding or removing the `-w` flag, no matter what the situation.

So what exactly does `cvs history -w` do?

Comment: Just for giggles, what happens if you do `cvs history -xM -w`? I'm wondering if `-e` is conflicting with the `-w`

Comment: I had that thought too - but I tried it and as far as I can tell, -w is just ignored. It does nothing no matter what other options I tack on there, from -xTOEFWUPCMGAR -w to plain -w and everything in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.

Digging through the CVS source code revealed that the -w option to history set a flag called 'working' which is then used in the function `accept_hrec()` in the following lines:

```
if (!hr                 /* The last record */
    || !STREQ (hr->user, lr->user)  /* User has changed */
    || !STREQ (hr->mod, lr->mod)    /* Module has changed */
    || (working             /* If must match "workdir" */
        && (!STREQ (hr->dir, lr->dir)   /* and the 1st parts or */
        || !STREQ (hr->end, lr->end))))/* the 2nd parts differ */

    return 1;

if (working)
{                   /* If must match "workdir" */
    if (!STREQ (hr->dir, lr->dir)   /*    and the 1st parts or */
    || !STREQ (hr->end, lr->end))   /*    the 2nd parts differ */
    return 1;
}
```

From comments earlier in the code, we find that `hr` and `lr` are both of type `struct hrec` - a record read from a single line in the history file. The list has been sorted by first the repository's root directory, and second the filename itself. `hr` points to the next record in our list, and `lr` to the current one. Further, `hrec.dir` and `hrec.end` represent a path - the first part (`dir`) tracks the root directory of the repository, and `end` tracks the directory within the repository (after some compression, etc.).

Now, `accept_hrec` is designed to return non-zero if we want to print out this hrec. So, we see that both of the 'working' conditions above simplify to the same:

`if (working && !STREQ (hr->dir, lr->dir) && !STREQ (hr->end, lr->end)) return 1`

ie. returning NON-ZERO if the directory/end combinations do NOT match. Since our list is sorted by path and file, that combination will differ ONLY when we've finished reading all the hrecs for that file.

So finally we are at a point where we can say for sure what the difference between `history` and `history -w` is.

`history` iterates over the list of entries in the history file, sorted by the repository the action was taken in, and then by the filename itself. Whenever it comes across a change in filename (ie. the last recorded action taken on that file), it checks: is this record a 'checkout' record? If so, print it - this file is checked out currently.

`history -w` does the exact same - except it considers a change in the filename OR a change in the repository directory to be the 'last recorded action'. Therefore, `cvs history -w` will always print out a superset of `cvs history`.

This, unfortunately, doesn't help the problem I was having, since CVS tracks the 'repository directory' of any and all remote clients as  - meaning I'm definitely not able to get 'this repo's last update time' like I wanted to. But at least I know what was going on now.